# SQL code to open a stored procedure and read it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using an interface that only allows me to use SQL commands. The database is SQL Server. Right now I need to open a stored procedure and read what is inside of it. What is the SQL command to open a stored procedure for reading? Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourSchemaName.YourProcedureName')
```

Comment: Always nice to see use of sys.sql_modules rather than syscomments and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA rubbish

Comment: @Fosco: This returns a single `nvarchar(max)` result. [sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) "displays the definition that is used to create an object in multiple rows. Each row contains 255 characters of the Transact-SQL definition."

Comment: Ah... With results-to-text there is no issue with 255 character limit.  It would be silly to use results-to-table, absolutely.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the long delay confirming the right answer. Just today I got back to this issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
sp_helptext 'dbo.myStoredProc'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.myStoredProc'))
```

Note: subject to [Metadata Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) and [VIEW DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808%28SQL.90%29.aspx) rights

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM syscomments
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '<NAME>')
ORDER BY colid
```